# Monthly Archive posts by category-wise

Tags: php, archiving

I have set my monthly Archive page (Archive.php) as like this :
[Monthly Archive](http://wordpress.pastebin.com/bZD6gi0r)
When clicking on any MONTH, the result will show all the posts for that particular month as below:

- Post title-1 ------ Category-1 ------
  Author name
- Post title-2 ------ Category-1 ------
  Author name
- Post title-3 ------ Category-1 ------
  Author name
- Post title-4 ------ Category-1 ------
  Author name
- Post title-5 ------ Category-1 ------
  Author name

But ... I want a display like this :

**Category-1**

- Post title-1 ------ Author name Post
- Post title-2 ------ Author name Post

**Category-2**

- Post title-3 ------ Author name Post
- Post title-4 ------ Author name Post
- Post title-5 ------ Author name Post

Comment: And the question is ...?

Comment: @ Kel : The question is : How can I arrange the code to display the monthly archives as mentioned in my post?

Answer (score 0):

This would be done when you display your data:

```
$pCategory = '';
$itemDisplay = '';
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($pCategory != $item['category']) {
        $itemDisplay .= '<b>' . $item['category'] . '</b><br><br>';
        $pCategory = $item['category'];
    }
    $itemDisplay .= '    ' . $item['title'] . ' by ' .
                             $item['author'] . '<br>';
}

echo $itemDisplay;
```

This is of course a rough example. You will have to tailor it to coincide with your code and database structure etc.